# HTTP calls in Xamarin.iOS app crashes when sending app to background

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, httpclient

I am using C# HttpClient to send HTTP call in my Xamarin.iOS apps. But when I send my app to background or even when the call is sent I open control center or notification center my app crashes gives OperationCanceledException. I am using delegates as callback in these calls when ever I get a response from server.
Is there any way to stop my app from crashing. Here is the following example of my code.

```
    public async void LoginVerify(APIDelegate<Response<bool>> callback)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(IP);
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login_code", Login_Code),
                });
                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeOutTime));
                var result = await client.PostAsync("/dev", content, cts.Token);
                string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                Response<bool> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<bool>>(resultContent);
                callback(response);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            callback(new Response<bool> { ErrorMsg = Params.NoInternet_error, Message = Params.NoInternet_error, Data = false, StatusCode = int.Parse(Params.NoInternet_code) });
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
        {
            callback(new Response<bool> { ErrorMsg = Params.Main_error, Message = Params.JsonDeserialize_error + " in LoginVerify Function", Data = false, StatusCode = int.Parse(Params.JsonDeserialize_error_code) });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            callback(new Response<bool> { ErrorMsg = Params.Main_error, Message = ex.Message + " :: " + ex.StackTrace +" in LoginVerify Function", Data = false, StatusCode = int.Parse(Params.AppInternalIssue_code) });
        }
    }
```

After I receive the response, I use my delegate like this:

```
        void Login(string ntlogin)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!CheckInternetConnection())
                {
                    NoInternetError();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (toast != null)
                        toast.Dismiss();
                    API.Login_Code = code_first.Text + code_second.Text + code_third.Text + code_fourth.Text;

                    API.LoginVerify((responseVerify) =>
                    {
                        if (responseVerify != null)
                        {
                            if (responseVerify.StatusCode == 200)
                            {
                                if (responseVerify.Data)
                                {
                                    API.Data((response) =>
                                    {
                                        _timer.Stop();
                                    //If No Exception Is Thrown
                                        if (response != null)
                                        {
                                            if (response.StatusCode == 200 || response.StatusCode == 202)
                                            {
                                                tab. = response.Data;

                                                //del.Window.RootViewController = nav;
                                                UIView.Transition(del.Window, 0.5, UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, () =>
                                                {
                                                    del.Window.RootViewController = tab;
                                                }, null);

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                ErrorLog(response.Message, response.Message + " Error while fetching  details on SplashController.", Params.AppInternalIssue_code);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ErrorLog(Params.Main_error, "  Details returned null on Splash Controller.", Params.AppInternalIssue_code);
                                        }

                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            loadPop.Hide();
                            ErrorLog(Params.Main_error, responseVerify.Message, Params.AppInternalIssue_code);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLog(Params.Main_error, ex.Message + " :: " +  ex.StackTrace + " :: LoginSMSController func Login", Params.AppInternalIssue_code);
            }
        }
```

This is the exception that is being raised.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
      at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001d4] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.16.0.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs:462 
      at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506 
      at API.Entities.Support.SupportAPI.SupportData (API.Entities.Support.SupportAPI+SupportAPIDelegate`1[T] callback) [0x001ab] in /Users/zshakil/Desktop/Projects/Support/API/Entities/SupportAPI.cs:271 }
```

Screenshot for line no: 271
[image]

Comment: Did you try to create an "Exception catchpoint" in visual studio, or did you try to place breakpoints and step through your code and see exactly on which line the exception is caught and the app is crashing?

Comment: whenever the call is sent to server and I send my app to background I get this error OperationCanceledException. The exception occurs when my app is waiting for server response.

Comment: Zeeshan, your app already handles that exception well, it should not crash on that line. There is another exception caught which crashes your app because it is not handled. That’s basically how error handling works.

Comment: Yes, I need my app to work smoothly even when the app is in the background. Is there any way to send an http call without raising this exception??

Comment: Can you please share us the stacktrace?